# Generate a vector m with the small letters from a to j in alphabetical order?

Tags: r

How do I generate a vector m with the small letters from a to j (in alphabetical order).

Comment: `m <- letters[1:10]`  I assume that you are not looking for `sample`.

Comment: @akrun, post as answer?

Comment: but it *is* an answer ...

Comment: Error: could not find function "letters" this is what I keep getting?

Comment: @Chris I am using R 3.1.2 on linux.  I couldn't reproduce your error.

Comment: ok I got it Thanks, I have 2 more that I could use your help with. Add the numbers from 1 to 50 to the numbers 100 to 51 respectively.

Comment: @Chris May be `1:50 +100:51`.  But this will get you a vector of `101`. Or may be you are referring to `outer(1:50,100:51, FUN='+')`

Comment: @Chris  letters is not  a function, it is rather a pre built structure in R. letters() will give you the error code, however letters[ ] with  the square brackets should not.

Answer (score 2):

`R` has built-in constants `letters`, `LETTERS`  for `lower-case` and `upper-case` letters of Roman alphabet. If you want to generate a vector from `a` to `j` i.e the first `10` alphabets.

```
m <- letters[1:10]
```

Comment: Ok how would I Generate a vector n with the small letters from a to j (in random order)?

Comment: `sample(letters[1:10])`

Comment: Okay I could use some help with this one. I need to generate a data frame abc that contains the letters from "a" to "j" in the first column and the integers from 10 to 1 in the second column. Make sure the first column is called "LETTERS" and the second "NUMBERS".
Thanks for your help